# plink serial from windows to linux does not echo password correctly

Tags: cmd, serial-port, plink

My Use case:

I have a hyper-v host set up with linux guests. These linux guests have no ip set up initially on boot so I cannot ssh into them.

I am trying to automate setup hence why I am trying to script the build without the use of using the GUI console login. My solution would be to go in through the serial connection to setup the needed network before finishing up the rest of my build.

I am trying to not add additional software or stuff to the base vm template.

I have tried using plink and hvc but running into the same problem.

In the windows CMD, I run the following:

```
(
echo User
timeout /t 5 > nul
echo SuperSecret) | plink -serial \\.\pipe\COM1
```

which seems to work as I get the following output

```
localhost login: User

Password:
Login incorrect
```

It echo's the username correctly but the password does not seem to work. I am unsure if this is how windows's echo is outputting the password to the linux serial console. I am stumped.

Comment: Are there any characters in your password which are poisonousto the echo command? Also you may need to check that there is no unwanted whitespace suffixed to the end of it too.

Comment: Append `^& rem/` to the `echo` commands (like `echo User^&rem/`) to avoid trailing whitespaces and try again; what happens then?

Comment: ^& rem/ was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

adding ^&rem/ worked.

from aschipfl@

```
(
echo User^&rem/
timeout /t 5 > nul
echo SuperSecret^&rem/) | plink -serial \\.\pipe\COM1
```